# Database Failover not happening for Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, failover

I have a Sharepoint 2016 farm with shared roles in the following configuration.

- 2 X Web Front End Servers with Distributed Cache
- 2 X Application Servers with Search
- 1 X Domain Controller
- 2 X SQL Servers in Failover Cluster (configured with High
  Availability)

However when I do a Manual failover from DB-Server-1 to DB-Server-2 , the failover happens successfully but I get the following errors.

"*Cannot update database on SQL Server instance 'SQL-LISTENER-01'.  Database is read/only. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
Failed to update database "SharePoint_Config" because the database is read-only.*"

"*SQL database login for 'SharePoint_Config' on instance 'SQL-LISTENER-01' failed. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
Login failed for user 'TEST-DOMAIN\SPFarm'.*"

Shutting down the DB-Server-2 has no effect and the sharepoint farm works fine. But setting DB-Server-1 as secondary and DB-Server-2 as primary causes the sharepoint farm to go down.

Comment: Is SharePoint using the AOAG Listener as the endpoint?

Comment: Did you setup SQL permissions for your service accounts on DB-Server-2?

Comment: @TrevorSeward I am using AOAG.